# Is every smooth projective curve a modular curve?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I have seen a quote saying that

> Every smooth projective curve over a number field is a modular curve, i.e. (compactification of) $\Gamma\backslash\mathcal{H}$ for some finite index subgroup $\Gamma<\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and $\mathcal{H}$ is the upper half plane.

Here, $\Gamma$ is not necessarily a congruence subgroup. The author says that this is because of Belyi's Theorem. Could anyone explain how one can get such implication from Belyi's Theorem? Any reference would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Belyi's theorem says that every smooth projective curve $X$ over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is a cover of $\mathbb{P}^1$ ramified above 3 points. The key is to find a modular curve that is a thrice-punctured $\mathbb{P}^1$ without elliptic points. The classic example is the modular curve $\mathcal{H}/\Gamma(2)$. Let $X^*$ be the preimage of the branch points in $\mathbb{P}^1$, then $X^*\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^1 - \{3 \text{ points}\}\cong\mathcal{H}/\Gamma(2)$ is an unramified cover. Since the image of $\Gamma(2)$ in $\text{Aut}(\mathcal{H})\cong\text{PSL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ acts freely on $\mathcal{H}$, $\mathcal{H}$ is the universal cover of $\mathcal{H}/\Gamma(2)$, and every intermediate cover takes the form $\mathcal{H}/\Gamma$ for some $\Gamma\le\Gamma(2)$. In particular, applying this to $X^*$, we find that $X^*\rightarrow\mathcal{H}/\Gamma(2)$ is of the form $\mathcal{H}/\Gamma\rightarrow\mathcal{H}/\Gamma(2)$. Taking smooth compactifications, we find that $X$ is the smooth compactification of $\mathcal{H}/\Gamma$.

Note: Since $-I\in\Gamma(2)$, it might be cleaner to use an index 2 subgroup of $\Gamma(2)$ which does not contain $-I$. There are four such subgroups. One of them is the Sanov subgroup, freely generated by $[[1,2],[0,1]]$ and $[[1,0],[2,1]]$. It acts freely on $\mathcal{H}$ and has the same image in $\text{Aut}(\mathcal{H})$ as $\Gamma(2)$.

Comment: Do you know that if the full list of $\Gamma$s' such that the associated modular curve is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1-\{3\text{ points}\}$ is known?

Comment: @User0829 For the congruence ones, you can find a complete list of the genus 0 congruence modular curves [here](https://mathstats.uncg.edu/sites/pauli/congruence/csg0.html). In general, you can think of modular curves as given by permutation representations of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$. The ramification above 0,1728,infinity can be calculated from the images of the standard generators $(E,V,EV)$, where $E$ has order 4, $V$ has order 6, and $EV$ is conjugate to $[[1,1],[0,1]]$. From this you can calculate the genus, number of cusps,...etc